# How to create complex types with Azure Stream Analytics queries

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I try to transform flat JSON data from an Event Hub into a DocumentDB. The target structure should look like:

```
{
   "id" : 1
   "field_1" : "value_1",
   "details" : {
      "detail_field_1":"abc",
      "detail_field_2":"def"
   }
}
```

Created from source:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "field_1" : "value_1",
   "detail_field_1":"abc",
   "detail_field_2":"def"
}
```

I checked the documentation of Azure Stream Analytics but there ist no clear description how to create a proper Query.

Who one can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage [the new JavaScript UDF feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) to write nested JSON objects to output.

Register a user-defined function, "UDF.getDetails()" as below:

```
function main(obj) {
  //get details object from input payload
  var details_obj = {};

  details_obj.detail_field_1 = obj.detail_field_1;
  details_obj.detail_field_2 = obj.detail_field_2;

  return JSON.stringify(details_obj);
}
```

Then call the UDF in your query to get a string of the nested JSON object.

```
SELECT
  id,
  field_1,
  UDF.getDetails(input) As details
INTO output
FROM input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript UDF feature, you can return complex JSON.
Example write function.

```
function main(obj) {
//get details object from input payload
var details_obj = {};

details_obj.detail_field_1 = obj.detail_field_1;
details_obj.detail_field_2 = obj.detail_field_2;

 return details_obj;
}
```

You should not use JSON.stringify since it will make it a string instead of JSON object.

Use it like.

```
SELECT id,  field_1, UDF.getDetails(input) As details
INTO output
FROM input
```